# error with tkinter python always recive error but no correct conditions

Tags: python, windows, user-interface, tkinter, radio-button

why does this code fail

im trying to summon a window when the settings button is pressed that allows users to change the forground and background colours

i get the radio buttons but recive an error every time i submit the colours even though their value is not 0

how do i fix this and why does it happen?

```
from tkinter import *
import os
from tkinter import messagebox as mgb
import tkinter.ttk as tk2

global colour_1, colour_2
colour_1 = "pink"
colour_2 = "purple" #background

def sayclick() :
    btn.configure(text = "saying")
    text = txt.get()
    os.system("""PowerShell -Command "Add-Type –AssemblyName System.Speech; (New-Object System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer).Speak('""" + text + """ ');" """)
    btn.configure(text = "say")

def colourmenu():
    window = Tk()

    window.title("colour menu")

    selected = IntVar()
    selected2 = IntVar()

    rad11 = tk2.Radiobutton(window,text='blue  ', value=1, variable=selected)# set 1

    rad21 = tk2.Radiobutton(window,text='green', value=2, variable=selected)#

    rad31 = tk2.Radiobutton(window,text='red   ', value=3, variable=selected)#

    rad41 = tk2.Radiobutton(window,text='black', value=4, variable=selected)#

    rad12 = tk2.Radiobutton(window,text='blue ', value=1, variable=selected2)

    rad22 = tk2.Radiobutton(window,text='green', value=2, variable=selected2)

    rad32 = tk2.Radiobutton(window,text='red  ', value=3, variable=selected2)

    rad42 = tk2.Radiobutton(window,text='black', value=4, variable=selected2)

    def submitbut():
       if selected.get() == 0 :
          mgb.showinfo("error", "error: invalid colour choise")
       elif selected2.get() == 0 :
          mgb.showinfo("error", "error: invalid colour choise")
       else :
          for n in range(1,3):
             if n == 1 :
                val = selected.get()
                rep = 1
             else :
                val = selected2.get()
                rep = 2
             if val == 1:
                colour = "blue"
             elif val == 2 :
                colour = "green"
             elif val == 3 :
                colour = "red"
             else :
                colour = "black"
             if rep == 1 :
                bg = colour
             else :
                fg = colour



    submit = Button(window, text="submit", command=submitbut)

    txt1 = Label(window, text = "background")
    txt1.grid(column = 0, row = 0)

    txt2 = Label(window, text = "forground")
    txt2.grid(column = 1, row = 0)
    rad11.grid(column=0, row=1)#set 1

    rad21.grid(column=0, row=2)#

    rad31.grid(column=0, row=3)#

    rad41.grid(column=0, row=4)#

    rad12.grid(column=1, row=1)

    rad22.grid(column=1, row=2)

    rad32.grid(column=1, row=3)

    rad42.grid(column=1, row=4)

    submit.grid(column=0, row=5)

    window.mainloop()


root = Tk()
root.geometry("170x120")
root.title("tts entry box")
root.configure(background = colour_2)

lab = Label(root, text = "enter text and than press\n\"say\" to say the text", font = ("Arial Bold", 10), fg = colour_2, bg = colour_1)
lab.grid(column = 0, row = 0)

btn = Button(root, text = "   say.   ", font = ("Arial", 8), bg = colour_1, fg = colour_2, command = sayclick)
btn.grid(column = 0, row = 3)

btn2 = Button(root, text = "settings", font = ("Arial", 8), bg = colour_1, fg = colour_2, command = colourmenu)
btn2.grid(column = 0, row = 4)

txt = Entry(root, width = 10, bg = colour_1, fg = colour_2)
txt.grid(column = 0, row = 2)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: should i just use another imput methord

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I notice that if I delete everything from `root = Tk()` to `root.mainloop()` and replace it with just `colourmenu()`, then `selected.get()` and `selected2.get()` return the correct values. Maybe it has something to do with that? I'm not sure if you're supposed to call `mainloop` more than once, for instance.

Comment: @Kevin You are allowed to do a `mainloop` inside a `mainloop`—it usually isn't a great idea, but it isn't causing the problem here. You're even allowed to create multiple independent root instances, Calling `mainloop` on one root does mean that the other root and all of its descendants are unresponsive until it finishes. (This used to be a hacky but occasionally useful way to fake modal dialogs in Classic Mac, Win16, and Motif, but it's not useful in most modern systems… but anyway, the OP hasn't noticed that problem.)

Comment: Why do people always downvote me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have two separate `Tk` objects in your program. This is almost always a bad idea, and the *reason* it's a bad idea is that it means that any code that relies on the "default `Tk` object" is likely to do the wrong thing.

In particular, when you do this:

```
selected = IntVar()
```

… you're creating an `IntVar` that's part of the first `Tk` that you created.<sup>1,2</sup> But the `Radiobutton` widgets are attached to a *different* `Tk`. So, they can't read those variables (that's why you start off with all of the radio buttons in indeterminate state), and they can't write to them either.<sup>3</sup>

If you want to create a new top-level window, you don't need to create a whole new Tk environment, just use a `Toplevel` widget:

```
def colormenu():
    window = Toplevel()
    # the rest of your code can be the same
```

And then, the `IntVar`s end up as part of the same `Tk` as the `window`.

---

While we're at it, do you really want to put a `mainloop` inside the other `mainloop`? This is legal, but I don't think it's what you want. It's almost certainly better to just return from `colormenu` after the `submit.grid` and let the main `mainloop` loop. (If you were trying to make `colormenu` a modal dialog, that blocks interaction with the main window, this isn't the way to do it.)

---

<sub>1. You *can* explicitly specify a parent when creating an `IntVar`, the same way you do for a widget. For example, `selected = IntVar(window)` would make this problem go away. But there are additional problems with having a separate `Tk` here, so it's better to solve them all at once by just not having one.</sub>

<sub>2. If you ever need to have multiple `Tk` instances, and need to know which one a variable, widget, etc. is attached to, you can look at its `_root` attribute. For example, `selected._root is window._root` will tell you whether they're part of the same `Tk` or not—in this case, it's False with your code as written, but True with the change in the next paragraph.</sub>

<sub>3. If you're curious why this isn't giving you a useful and easily-debuggable error, you have to understand how tkinter actually works. Tkinter is a wrapper around the Tk library, written in a completely separate scripting language called Tcl. Each `Tk` root instance has its own entirely independent Tcl interpreter, with its own independent global variables. So, your `selected = IntVar()` is creating a Tcl global variable named `PY_VAR0` inside your first Tcl interpreter. Then, your `variable=selected` tells Tcl to store changes to the global variable `PY_VAR0` in your second Tcl interpreter. So, whenever there's a change, Tcl writes to the global variable `PY_VAR0` in the second interpreter, which is perfectly legal, but perfectly useless, because your `selected` looks up `PY_VAR0` in the first interpreter.</sub>